# Azure App Service - Browsed Content not updated following Publish

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-web-app-service

We have an Azure App Service hosting a Web App that includes static HTML and JS content.  We have found that new JavaScript content we deploy to the Web Application is not updated in browsers until we Restart the Azure App Service.  We use MSBUILD driven MSDeploy to publish.

We have confirmed via Kudu that the new versions of our Java Script files are there.  The file sizes and modified date/time change with our deployments, as expected.

However if we hit them in a browser (e.g. http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/theFile.js) we see an older version of the file content.  This is regardless of browser, after deleting cache, running in Incognito mode, running w/ Cache Disabled in F12 Tools -- always get the old content.

If we merely restart the App Service via the Portal and re-browse we get the new content.  Viola, but what's going on?

The Azure App Service hosts an ASP.NET Web API application, at version 4.6.1, 64-bit, integrated pipeline, ARR `off`, Always On `on`.

The WebAPI application has a non-default Route defined that serves out a static HTML file.  That file has a link to a static JS file stored in the same folder, side-by-side, as the HTML file.  We've no specific route for the JS file...but didn't think that was necessary.

The environment variable `WEBSITE_LOCALCACHE_ENABLED = False`.

Any tips or help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue corresponded to a point in our project where we were not properly updating the .NET Assembly versions during our deployments.  Once we modified our code and build process to generate a new AssemblyVersion with each deployment the problem went away.

In other words, now that we're always deploying with a new 4-part .NET version we always receive the right (currently sitting in Azure) version of our Java Script files.

I note that we never, ever (and still don't) change the name of our index.html or JavaScript files.

We didn't change any Routes or Azure settings -- just correctly incremented the version.  I don't have a precise explanation but this is what we now observe and are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable client cache for static contents in your web application? If you have, you can disable the cache:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache  cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Interestingly we do have a `<staticContent>` block in our web.config but it is entirely commented out.

Is the default IIS `clientCacheMode` enabled?

Comment: Please look at your code. If the static cache is enabled at some other places, and by default, IIS does not enable client-cache. Cheers.

Comment: Don't think that's the issue -- there is no other configuration in play and we have zero code that plays with client-cache.  I note also that the issue is intermittent.  Sometimes we deploy and the new content is fetchable and other times it is not.

Comment: Do you have any CDN in play here?

Comment: Do  you have a try to restart the WebApp after add the configuration in the Web.config file? If it not, please have a try to restart the WebApp then try to  upload new file and visit in browser.

Comment: No we are not using a CDN.

Comment: @TomSun-MSFT Not sure I understand your recommendation.  Our experience:  things work as desired if we restart the Web App after Publishing.  Question:  Should we *always* restart the Web App (via the Restart button on the Portal) after Publishing, or might there be an issue in our code or configuration?

Comment: From my experience, there is no need to restart the Azure WebApp after  publishing. It is very odd. Do you have a try to create another WebApp to test it ?

Comment: We had a bug in our versioning scheme for .NET Assemblies.  Our WebAPI assembly was already being built with the same version.  We modified our scheme to stamp a new `a.b.c.d` `d` value for each build.  Since then we've not had the JS content issue.  We serve out our `blah.js` file via `/index.html`, which we have a route for in our WebAPI `WebApiConfig.Register`method.  This is perhaps a reach, but could it have been that an generated DLL was created by ASP.NET to serve out either `index.html` or `blah.js` and that ASP.NET messed up in versioning the generated file?